# sed command line to change "aas=aas" into "aas = aas"

Tags: regex, linux, macos, sed

A Questions for the regular expression/ sed experts out there:
I need to beautify some c++ code.
The code is littered with various version of the assignment operator with different types of spacing.
i.e.

```
a=b
a =b
a= B
a  = b
a=  b
A = B. // the correct format needed, and so must be ignored by SED
```

There should only be one space around the =. If more are found, the extras must be removed.

I need to make a script that will scan through all files in folder and subfolders and search and replace as needed.

There are some variations, like the a+=b etc.

I run on OsX but have linux and windows machines available.

help much appreciated.

Comment: What's expected output for `a+=b` and `a*=b` etc?

Comment: You might be able to just run it through clang format

Comment: the expected answers for a+=b and a*=b would be a += b and a *= b

Comment: @nathan, tel me more about clang format...

Comment: @ jarod42:I have a simple text file with some tests: 
`>> cat regtest.txt 
a=b
asas asasa=bddfdf
a =dfdf
sasasa= ssdsd
sdsd = sdsdsd
RESULT:
>> sed 's/([^ =])+ *([=+*/%-]?=)( )*([^ ])/$1 $2 $3/' regtest.txt 
a=b
asas asasa=bddfdf
a =dfdf
sasasa= ssdsd
sdsd = sdsdsd`

Comment: After some tries, `sed -e 's/ *\([+=*/%]\?=\) */ \1\ /g'` seems to do the jobs.

Comment: Jarod, I am sure yours should work, but on osx, it seems to have some incompatibility. What are you testing on?

Comment: To all the guys that took the time to answer, THANKS A LOT!! MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: Obvious answer: use a C++ beautifier instead of trying to write something in sed. [Google it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+beautifier&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to insert a single space before and after all `=` operators:

**Input file:**

```
cat file
a          ==b
a=b
a =b
a/=b
a *=b
a+= b
a-=   b
a= B
a%= B
a  = b
a=  b
A = B
```

**`sed` command:**

```
sed -E 's~[[:blank:]]*([-+*/%=]?=)[[:blank:]]*~ \1 ~g' file

a == b
a = b
a = b
a /= b
a *= b
a += b
a -= b
a = B
a %= B
a = b
a = b
A = B
```

This is regex used for matching (using `~` as delimiter):

- `~[[:blank:]]*([-+*/%=]?=)[[:blank:]]*~` - matches 0 or more white spaces followed by an optional `-+*/%=` characters before a literal `=`. We are also capturing this operator in group #1

This is patter used in replacement:

- `~ \1 ~` Which means a space before and after string captured in group #1

Comment: I look at that regex and it looks like a swearword. ;>)
I tested it with my simpler file and it works fine.
You do not maybe feel like doing some education and explain the regex? Then maybe me and someone else can learn also from it.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer.

Comment: I tried to also add the "!" and "<" to the exclusion list with no luck by changing it to:
    sed -E 's~[[:blank:]]*([-+*!</%=]?=)[[:blank:]]*~ \1 ~g' file

Any idea why?

Comment: Try this: `sed -E 's~[[:blank:]]*([-!<+*/%=]?=)[[:blank:]]*~ \1 ~g' file`

Comment: You swapped the sequence inside the [ ]. Does not work, I end up with "! =" i.e. space in between ! and =.

I also tried escaping the '!' with /, but also no luck.

Comment: `sed -E 's~[[:blank:]]*([-!<+*/%=]?=)[[:blank:]]*~ \1 ~g' <<< 'a!=b'` works for me and gives `a != b`.

Comment: SORRY, it is working. I must have broken my original file early when I was testing. So it had already ! = instead of !=.

Answer (score 0):

It may interest you doing it with `Perl`

A simple `file.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int i =          3;
    i     += 3;
    i-=3;
    i   *  =    3; // not valid just for sure
    i/=3;

    int i2
    =
    3;

    if( i
       =
       = i2 ){} // not valid just for sure
}
```

`perl -lpe '$/=undef;s/\s*([=!%\*\/+-])?\s*(=)\s*/ $1$2 /g' file.cpp`

the output:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int i = 3;
    i += 3;
    i -= 3;
    i *= 3;
    i /= 3;

    int i2 = 3;

    if( i == i2 ){}
}
```